# Secure raw SQL query in Django with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, django, security, sql-injection

I am creating a web application using django framework. In one of the SQL queries I had to join multiple tables and use the user input as part of the "where" clause to fetch the results. Since the query was rather complex, I chose to use raw SQL instead of django framework.

A simplified form of the query is :

```
select * from table where {where_clause}
```

`where_clause` would be something of the form `col1>100 and col2>50 and col3 <40` and so on
This part is created on the front end based on the user input (sort of like a stock screener).

To make the query secure against SQL injection, I decided to use `psycopg2` which builds the query as :

```
query = sql.SQL("select {field} from {table} where {pkey} = %s").format(
    field=sql.Identifier('my_name'),
    table=sql.Identifier('some_table'),
    pkey=sql.Identifier('id'))
```

Even if I separate all the parts of `where_clause` into identifiers and literals, I do not know what all columns are there beforehand to write in this way. There could potentially be many columns which are chosen by the user to filter on.

How can I go about making the query secure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting a user define (or even know) your tables/columns names seems not secure at the first place.

I would create some dict of allowed values a user can filter by that map to actual tables in your db (so user doesn’t know your db column names).

Then instead of letting a user write ‘>’, ‘<‘ etc operators directly I’d provide a user with a dropdown of comparison operators to use.

So in the end a user would send to your backend a followind filter object:

```json
{
  “Field name 1”: {“value”: “some value”, “comparison_operator”: “greater_than”,
  “Filed name 2”: ...
}
```

Then on your backend convert these values to the sql where clause

Comment: Noted. It's somewhat similar to what I have done. But do you think this is enough to prevent SQL injection ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use the ‘format’ method instead of interpolating values to query string directly. Cause it would still be possible for a user to provide malicious code via “value” param